# HTML5 Video tag as URL

Tags: html, video

I am learning the new HTML5 tags, and have a question about the video tag that I cannot seem to find a good example/answer for.

Can I provide a source as a URL, or does the source have to route from the web server? I am just trying to play with an example to see what it looks like, and use a youtube video as the source. Is this possible?

Comment: what does *does the source have to route from the web server* mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source can indeed be a valid URL, which of course in this case needs to be a URL to a valid video file.

Comment: This does work, I just had a hell of a time finding a proper URL. Thanks.